# Create Slackbot reminder via Curl and Incoming Webook

Tags: shell, curl, slack

We use the [Incoming Webhook integration](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) for Slack for a lot of chat-ops related things.  What I'm trying to do is use this integration to be able to set a Slackbot reminder as part of a cron job on a server.  Right now I have a curl that looks like:

```
curl --data "/remind aparkin to do that thing in 45 mins" 'https://notmyrealteam.slack.com/services/hooks/slackbot?token=nottherealtoken&channel=%23testtesttest2'
```

But this just literally puts the text `/remind aparkin to do that thing in 45 mins` in the `#testtesttest2` room instead of creating the reminder.

I know the [web api allows you to do this](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add), but I really like the convenience of the incoming webhooks integration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a bot.  Flexibility > Convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can do that directly with an incomming webhook.

But you can develop a small script (e.g. PHP) that works as your very own webhook for the cron script. It just needs to parse the reminder parameter from your url and then use the [remind method](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add) of the WEB API to set the reminder on Slack.

Comment: I've been looking at the remind.add method in the docs, but it seems to have some limitations. It only takes a user id and can't post to a channel or group.


```
// Initialize Slack Web Client
const SLACK_WEB = new WebClient(SLACK_BOT_USER_OAUTH_TOKEN);

async function setSlackReminder() {
  const result = await SLACK_WEB.reminders.add({
    token: SLACK_USER_OAUTH_TOKEN,
    text: "Hello there!",
    time: "in 15 minutes",
    user: "XXXXXX",
  });

  console.log(result);
}
```